# How do I keep C# objects in scope so I can access and change values throughout my program?

Tags: c#, class, global-variables

Good day,

This is a generic question.

I am fairly new to C# so I've been reading/completing several tutorials and books on C# for the beginner.  I am attempting to create a game based on stock market trading.  The intent is to create 80 companies from 4 different countries, and each country will have the same 10 different commodities.  These companies will have 100k stocks each for sale at the start of the game.  I tried to track all this by using a Company class which tracks the Name, country, commodity, beginning price, last turn price, stocks available and a few other parameters.  The problem I have seems to with "scope", as I'm unable to either access the objects created, or make changes to them.  My tutorials don't seem to go into detail on that subject other than to say that C# does not support Global Scope as previous languages did.  I don't want to declare the variables in the "Main" block - I thought that is why you create a new class (using the Class Wizard).

I am looking for a suggestion to get me started - I am not looking for the solution (Not yet, lol) just where should I look?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. But there is something missing from your question. What is your goal and your difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, your development environment and the data structures, as well as to share more code (no screenshot), some samples, images or sketches of the screen, and user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, please read the *[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* and **Questions I avoid asking** at the top right.

Comment: Can you add some code, please?

Comment: What UI technology are you using? Windows Forms, WPF, ASP, Console, ...?

Comment: *"I don't want to declare the variables in the "Main" block"* - Why not?  If they belong there then it's a perfectly good place to declare them.  *"I thought that is why you create a new class"* - Which itself would be referenced by a variable, no?  And if that class itself contains the engine for your stock trading system, maybe you declare your variables in there?  It's not really clear exactly what problem you've encountered.

Comment: _using the Class Wizard_  - Curious: What would that be?

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in the comments above, it's not 100% clear what exactly is your problem - but I'll try to steer you in a direction that may help. My understanding is that you'd like to have a sort of "central" object that stores the game's state and that can be accessed from different classes and scopes throughout your code. I would suggest you take a look at [Static Classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members).

A static class is a class that has only one, global, instance. This means that you can access any information stored in the scope of that static class from anywhere in your program. An example of a simple class that may hold the info you need would be something like this -

```
public static class GameState
{
    public static List<Company> Companies = new List<Companies>();
    public static List<Country> Countries = new List<Country>();
    public static List<Commodity> Commodities= new List<Commodity>();
}
```

Using something like this you could access any of these static members (`Companies`, `Countries`, `Commodities`) anywhere in your code, just by referencing your static class, for example

`var numOfCountries = GameState.Countries.Count`

> Just a comment before I end - I am not exactly advocating using this approach in any real application. It's not very good practice and it has many drawbacks - with the class I suggest above, for example, you can only have 1 game state throughout your entire program - imagine what would happen if you wanted to turn your program into a server that manages the state of many players' game in parallel. However, considering you mentioned that you are new to C#, I think this is the simplest solution that would help you get on your way.

Comment: Thank you Nimrod.  I will start with that.  As I mentioned, I am only looking for a general "Where should I start" and this is perfect.

Comment: No problem @TMaxwell86, happy this helps. If you feel this answers your needs, feel free to click the checkmark to the left. This is both the "StackOverflow" way of saying thanks and, more importantly, saves other people's time as they can see there's no need to answer this again (:
Happy coding!